# Not Being able to get and save profile picture of user in device by facebook-sdk-unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am not sure what is the cause of this problem but here it goes

i am using facebook-sdk-unity to get user's profile picture. 
instead of getting it from FB API,
i am hitting a url(which is aquired from graph api request for profile picture) with WWW class object
and instead of using yield return expression i am just running a loop untill i get www.isDone =  true

But the problem is it is never getting out of the loop. so my code is freezing.

in unity editor it works fine.
this problem only occurs on devices.

i have cross checked hitting image url in browser. i am getting an image in browser already, nothing wrong there.
**here is my code :-**

```
public GameObject cube;

void Start () 
{
    try
    {
        saveUserProfilePICFromURL("https://graph.facebook.com/{facebook-id of user}/picture");
        WWW www = new WWW ("file://"+Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserPIC.png");
        while(!www.isDone);
        cube.renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
    catch(System.Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Exception: WebServices_Start "+e.Message);
    }   
}


internal void saveUserProfilePICFromURL(string targetURL)
{
    targetURL = targetURL.Replace(@"\/","/");
    Debug.Log ("target url "+targetURL);
    WWW www = new WWW(targetURL);
    //yield return www;
    Debug.Log ("www.isStarted ");
    int i = 0;
    while(!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log ("www.isInProgress "+i);// program gets trapped in this loop
        i++;
    };
    Debug.Log ("www.isDone ");
    Texture2D PIC = www.texture;
    //cube.renderer.material.mainTexture = PIC;
    byte[] bytes = PIC.EncodeToPNG();
    Debug.Log ("PIC data length "+bytes.Length);
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserPIC.png";
    Debug.Log ("path "+path);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
}
```

So the problem is program never gets out of the loop.

how ever if i use the following code for downloading image. i get the image but its always empty. :-

```
internal void saveUserProfilePICFromURL(string targetURL)
{
    string destinationURL = Application.persistentDataPath + "/UserPIC.png";
    targetURL = targetURL.Replace(@"\/","/");
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync (new Uri (targetURL), destinationURL);
}
```